# Tried unmasking systemd-timesyncd and got deleted

Tags: command-line, services

So lately I was trying to sync my system time with an NTP time server using `timedatectl` command but I got this error:

```
Failed to set ntp : NTP is not supported
```

I searched the web and i figured out that systemd-timesyncd may be masked , so I tried unmasking it but it got deleted :

```
$ sudo systemctl unmask systemd-timesyncd
Removed /etc/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service
```

I went digging the web again and saw someone mention that I can't unmask systemd-timesyncd if ntp service is enabled . I tried installing systemd-timesyncd again and this time the ntp service got masked.I'm little newbie in this stuff, can anyone please explain to me why this happened? And why process can be masked on its own without any interference from the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

systemd-timesyncd implements SNTP instead of NTP.  If you only need loose occasional correct time, this might work.

But if you really want ntp, you want ntpd, chrony, or ntpsec, not systemd-timesyncd.

systemd-timesyncd actually interferes with ntpd functioning correctly, so if you want ntpd, it must be masked and/or removed.